# Breadcrumb and ellipsis with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css, breadcrumbs, tailwind-3

Here is a snippet of a basic breadcrumb using Tailwind:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="max-w-md">
<ul class="flex items-center">
  <li class="flex items-center">
    <a href="">
      <svg class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M2.25 12l8.954-8.955c.44-.439 1.152-.439 1.591 0L21.75 12M4.5 9.75v10.125c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125H9.75v-4.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125h2.25c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V21h4.125c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.75M8.25 21h8.25"></path></svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="flex items-center">
    <svg class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.21 14.77a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06L11.168 10 7.23 6.29a.75.75 0 111.04-1.08l4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 010 1.08l-4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 01-1.06-.02z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    <a href="" class="truncate">First item with a long name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="flex items-center">
    <svg class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.21 14.77a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06L11.168 10 7.23 6.29a.75.75 0 111.04-1.08l4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 010 1.08l-4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 01-1.06-.02z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    <a href="" class="truncate">Second item with a long name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="flex items-center">
    <svg class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.21 14.77a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06L11.168 10 7.23 6.29a.75.75 0 111.04-1.08l4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 010 1.08l-4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 01-1.06-.02z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    <a href="" class="truncate">Current page with a long name</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to truncate automatically long items with ellipsis on small screens.
When I use `truncate` it does not apply.

And I don't want the `ul` to overflow from the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's the solution...

```html
<div class="max-w-md">
  <ul class="flex items-center">
    <li class="flex items-center">
      <a href="">
        <svg class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M2.25 12l8.954-8.955c.44-.439 1.152-.439 1.591 0L21.75 12M4.5 9.75v10.125c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125H9.75v-4.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125h2.25c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V21h4.125c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.75M8.25 21h8.25"></path></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex items-center overflow-hidden">
      <svg class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.21 14.77a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06L11.168 10 7.23 6.29a.75.75 0 111.04-1.08l4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 010 1.08l-4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 01-1.06-.02z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
      <a href="" class="truncate">First item with a long name</a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex items-center overflow-hidden">
      <svg class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.21 14.77a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06L11.168 10 7.23 6.29a.75.75 0 111.04-1.08l4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 010 1.08l-4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 01-1.06-.02z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
      <a href="" class="truncate">Second item with a long name</a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex items-center overflow-hidden">
      <svg class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.21 14.77a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06L11.168 10 7.23 6.29a.75.75 0 111.04-1.08l4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 010 1.08l-4.5 4.25a.75.75 0 01-1.06-.02z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
      <a href="" class="truncate">Current page with a long name</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The output you can find [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/SQB5VhNU8f)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to truncate the text inside the breadcrumb items. However, you have applied the truncate class to the list item `(<li>)` instead of the anchor tag `(<a>)`. The truncate class should be applied to the element directly containing the text you want to truncate.

Comment: Thanks, but when I apply the `truncate` on the `<a>`, the flex overflow the div, so the text are never truncated (see updated snippet on the question)